# Calling a webservice on one website from another website; both hosted on the same server

Tags: c#, web-services, iis, dns

I have a server serving multiple websites under one IP with bindings on specific URLs.

However, one of the sites I am hosting needs to pull data off a webservice (.asmx file) located in another IIS website on the same server. The code works fine locally but when we push the code to our server, it seems not to be able to locally resolve the lookup. (getting the dreaded 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'. I think what's happening is it tries to use the endpoint address and do a DNS lookup, but because the DNS lookup ends up resolving to the same IP, it actually pulls the traffic via in-memory or pipes or something and not network, which causes IIS not to bind to the correct site, and so the whole thing goes to pot.

Is there a way I can use the windows hosts file or other mechanism to fix this apparent DNS issue? Perhaps someone might shed light on this and maybe its not DNS at all. Thanks!

UPDATE - Here is a quick breakdown of the domains in question. Nothing is specifically coded or pointing to 'localhost'. Everyhing is using fully qualified domain names.

DomainA.com is a website that, when a form is submitted, calls a web service from DomainB.com. Both DomainA.com and DomainB.com are 'web sites' set up in IIS on the same server bound to the same external IP address. What I *believe* to be the problem is that DomainA.com, when the form is submitted, does a DNS lookup for DomainB.com, and when it finds that the domain is the same IP address, does not use the domain name when making the requests to DomainB.com. Without the domain name being used/sent, IIS doesn't know which site to connect to and the 'target machine actively refuses' the connection.

Comment: Most probably you are accessing webservice located in 2nd IIS via local address (i.e. localhost). Try using external DNS name or add localhost binding in IIS Manager.

Comment: Sorry Raman, that is not the case. I am using a fully-qualified URL.

Comment: No, none of these are using SSL, Matthew.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I am having a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to location to your webservice in a configuration file?

Take a look at the proxy class you generated to consume it.
The host is usually hardcoded into that file.

If you didn't use your production host to create that file(or service reference), it is pointing to your development webservice. This won't be accessible from your production machine.

Comment: Incorrect. The host is pointing to the correct URL on the production server. The problem is that the domain used in that URL points to the same IP that the website consuming the webservice has as well.